# Returning reference to a const pointer to const type

Tags: c++, pointers

Can you look at this example code:

```
class Test {
  int *a;
  int b;
 public:
  Test() : b(2)
  {
    a = new int(5);
  }

  const int * const& GetA() const
  {
    const int * const& c = a;
    return a;
  }

  const int& GetB()
  {
    return b;
  }

  ~Test()
  {
    delete a;
  }
};
```

And I get a warning on return a. Why is it wrong to return a reference to a const pointer to a const variable, but it's fine to return a reference to a const variable? By the way if I return c in GetA() it compiles just fine.

Comment: What warning do you get?

Comment: Cannot reproduce a problem on VS 2015

Comment: I get returning reference to temporary [-Wreturn-local-addr].

Answer (score 1):

Consider first `const int& GetB()`. That's a neat way of returning a reference to the class member `b` that *can't* be modified at the call site. You may as well mark that function `const` since you are not changing any of the class member data. This is idiomatic C++, especially for types larger than an `int`, e.g. `std::string`.

When you write `return a;`, you are permitting the function call site to modify that class member through that pointer. Although the C++ standard allows this, it circumvents encapsulation and your friendly compiler is warning you of that. Note that since the function itself is *not* changing the class member, compilation passes despite it being marked as `const`.

In writing `const int * const& c = a;` the compiler assumes you know what you're doing.

(As a final note, all havoc is let loose if you attempt to copy an instance of `Test` due to the compiler generated copy constructor shallow-copying `a`. You ought to `delete` the copy constructor and the assignment operators.)

Comment: This is clear, however, when I write for example `std::cout << *(t->GetA());` I get a segfault. But when I return c the code works fine.